# Complex query regarding last run date

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Ah logic is frying my brain!

I have an Archive table that logs the RunDate of when a certain task is run. Looks something like this, but there are many records with the same TaskID and different dates of run.

[image]

I need to query this table to look for tasks that haven't been run this month.

This is how far I've got:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TaskID FROM tbl_Archive WHERE RunDate <= DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), 1))  AS sub INNER JOIN tbl_Task ON sub.TaskID = tbl_Task.TaskID
WHERE (((tbl_Task.Frequency)="Monthly"));
```

(I'm selecting DISTINCT because I only want to show the Task once)

This brings up Archive records of tasks that haven't run this month, but the problem is, it doesn't take into account if the task has been run this month.

So somehow I need to say exclude record if there is a date of this month.

I hope someone can clarify this simple-yet-so-difficult problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a NOT IN statement to exclude the ids that have been run this month

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TaskID FROM tbl_Archive 
WHERE RunDate <= DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), 1)
AND TaskID NOT IN 
(SELECT TaskID FROM tbl_Archive WHERE RunDate > DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), 1))
)  
AS sub INNER JOIN tbl_Task ON sub.TaskID = tbl_Task.TaskID
WHERE (((tbl_Task.Frequency)="Monthly"));
```

Comment: Perfect, worked a charm. I knew about the Not In function but for some reason it just didn't click in my mind. Can understand fully now. Thanks.